# Trying Freetds auto protocol

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I use Redhat Linux, Apache 2.4.7, PHP 5.4.24, Freetds 0.91, Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I currently use TDS version 7.0, all seems to work, but I think I should set the TDS version to 7.3. In order to be sure, I would like to try the auto protocol feature, as explained at the bottom of this page:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

I understand that I should set the version to 0, and let the libraries find out which TDS version is best.
I would like to do this only as an experiment, and then manually set the version in production.

My question is: after the libraries decide for a specific TDS version, how do I know which one it is? In other words, how do I ask the freetds which version of TDS it is using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can find the default TDS version (from [global] config) by using the `tsql` command line tool.

```
tsql -C
```

Additionally, it is probably best to use at *least* 7.2 for VARCHAR(MAX) (and friends) support. 7.3 offers support for more, however, it can be problematic with things like Django, since some Django / pyodbc modules don't pick the correct column type for actual use. So use 7.2 unless you absolutely need the column types supported in 7.3. See here:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm